# Mozilla Cookies Framework (issue!)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cookies, mozilla

So i'm getting started with cookies and saw this easy cookies framework provided by Mozilla,

I learned about adding a new cookie, But i'm having a weird issue when reading or getting the cookie.

okay here's buy code i'm writing:

```
// Cookies
const cookiesFn = () => {
    $(".bg-dark-change").on('click', function () {
        let bodyBlack = document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
        docCookies.setItem('BackgroundColor', bodyBlack, Infinity)
    })

}; cookiesFn();

docCookies.getItem('BackgroundColor');
// Cookies End
```

as you can see above this is my code i'm trying to achieve..

ohh yea here's the frame work links:
[Github](https://github.com/madmurphy/cookies.js)
[On Mozilla's Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework)

Comment: Can you explain what this "weird issue" is? What's not behaving as expected?

Comment: I'm able to add the cookie, but can't read it again!, means on reload the background will be again white!

Comment: Are you sure the cookie isn't getting set? You're showing the code where you're _setting_ and _reading_ the cookie but not where you're _using_ the cookie value.

Comment: I would appreciate it of you cleared out things for, as i said before I'm still digging into cookies..thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear whether your code is exactly as posted or if you've left off important details. You haven't made it clear whether you're not able to read the cookie or if you're just expecting the background color to change without you having code that's changing the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are just a dumb way of storing a piece of data in a browser that can be read later on. They don't actually *do* anything besides that. It's not clear whether you've actually looked to see if the cookie exists, but if your reading of the cookie is simply the same as the code you've posted, it's not enough. You actually have to *do something* with the cookie after reading it. For example, this code will set the background color if the cookie is present:

```
const backgroundColorCookie = docCookies.getItem('BackgroundColor');
if (backgroundColorCookie) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColorCookie;
}

$(".bg-dark-change").on('click', function () {
  let bodyBlack = document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
  docCookies.setItem('BackgroundColor', bodyBlack, Infinity)
});
```